# How can I open my old .snt file? I don't have \appdata\roaming folder in my Win7

Tags: windows-7

My old computer crashed but was able to save the snt file and copy to my new laptop but can't open it.

I don't have any Appdata\roaming folder in my Win7 to copy the snt file. Where is it? If I copy it or open it with the Stikynot.exe, only the new notes pops up.

Answer (score 0):

The appdata\roaming is, but this hidden:

```
C:\Users\Your_User_name\AppData\Roaming
```

You can click on Start and in Search program and files, write and enter:

```
%appdata%
or
%appdata%\roaming
```